# The place of an Ember.js App

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like the perspective of more experienced programmers on the place and use of an Ember.js app.

Initially, I thought Ember.js would be similar to Express, Rails, or CodeIgniter in that they are full fledged frameworks for developing content on many pages.

However, the more I delve into Ember, it appears that it is designed for apps on a single page where the content can change dynamically due to the user's interaction (due in part to a misunderstanding on my part of what a single page app is).

Am I correct? And what are some good examples of sites/apps built with Ember.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used it for building two full enterprise SPA, one backed by django-rest the other backed by web-api.  They are completely Ember, not just web-components etc.

That being said perusing through the Ember users will give some fun examples http://emberjs.com/ember-users/

[Discourse](http://try.discourse.org/) is one of the bigger fully fledged sites built with Ember, they've been at it for a while.

Comment: First off, thanks for pointing out Discourse. I handnt heard of them before and its rather impressive.

Comment: Second, I was looking at their site with the ember inspector and the actual app they produce, the discussion board, is totally ember and its a beast. The rest of the site appears to be Rails. Still really impressive and I think I'm figuring out the place and use of an Ember app. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, whoops, I didn't see that bar, that's just in the demo site, http://discuss.emberjs.com/

Comment: discussing with a coworker, according to him, ember is actually intended to be used to create an entire site. he cited https://vine.co/ which, if you can log in, tries to create the feel of a native app. Something to think about